Why syntax private(get) doesn't provide in PHP 8.4?
PHP introduced asymmetric property visibility like private(set), nice.
But why is there no private(get)?
It could be useful for the dependency injection.
<?php
    final class Log() {
        public LogEngine $engine;
   
        public function add(): void {
            $this->engine->add();
        }

        public function remove(): void {
            $this->engine->remove();
        }
    }

    $log = new Log;

    $log->engine = new UserLog;

    $log->add();

In this case property $engine is public as setter, but private as getter …

What kind of answer are you expecting? Any sort of answer would just be speculation of the intentions and motivations of the developer(s).
